# Oauth 2.0 for Fusion Tables API in .NET

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-fusion-tables, windows-server-2012-r2

To automate updating a Google Fusion Table, we have created a .NET console application to which we have attached the file clientsecrets.json generated and downloaded from the Google administration console.

When I run the application locally, a browser window opens to authorize the use of the API with OAuth 2.0. Once it authorized the process executed properly.

However, when we run the application on the server where we want to schedule your daily execution, does not open the browser window and stating "One or more errors ocurred".

The server is a Windows Server 2012. The application is built on the .NET 4.5.1 and authorizing the code is as follows:

```
...

var service = new FusiontablesService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
{
    ApplicationName = "Fusion Tables Sample",
    HttpClientInitializer = Utils.Google.GetCredential().Result
});

...

public static async Task<UserCredential> GetCredential()
{
    using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        return await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                new[] { FusiontablesService.Scope.Fusiontables },
                "XXXXXXXXXXXX[user]", CancellationToken.None);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is just a hunch but have you tried `HttpClientInitializer = await Utils.Google.GetCredential()` instead of forcing it to run synchronously? It is a common source of exception. Though it runs fine locally, you might want to check it out.

Comment: make sure what ever user you are running on the server has access to %appData% default filedatastore is going to be putting credentials there unless you tell it otherwise.

Comment: My tutorial on FileDatastore might help http://www.daimto.com/google-net-filedatastore-demystified/

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need a *service account* that can be created from Google "IAM and Admin' Console: https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts. Once the service account is created, save its private key locally (preferably as JSON-file) and then create *BaseClientService.Initializer* from the credentials obtained from this file. Something like:

```
var scopes = new[] { FusiontablesService.Scope.Fusiontables };
using (var stream = new FileStream(keyFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
 {
 return GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream)
 .CreateScoped(scopes);
 }
```

Having such Initializer, just create the instance of FusiontablesService almost as you did:

```
        service = new FusiontablesService(
            new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = creds,
                ApplicationName = "Street Parking",
            });
```